# Batch development

Tags: batch-file, process, cmd

I run a program in batch file and I use /bg command to run it in background. My question is, how can I see the process in task manager? I am asking this because /bg hide also the process.

Comment: Noone can say what a mystery program does. A/ Look on the details tab /B type `tasklist /svc` and see if it's acting as a service.

Comment: I tried before and isn't there. Anyhow if know other command to start a process in background, and the process to be shown in the process list or at any other location, for example in quick lunch it would be great.

Comment: If it isn't there, it isn't running.

Comment: It is running because when I delete /bg from my script and I run it again, the previous lunch process reappears in the process list, so I have two process of the program.

Comment: You should remember that batch-files show up as `cmd.exe` or `windows command processor` in the taskmanager

Answer (score 0):

In task manager you may only be seeing processes running under your user, click the "Show processes from all users" to see all processes.

Comment: I tried before and isn't there. Anyhow if know other command to start a process in background, and the process to be shown on process list or at any other location, for example in quick lunch it would be great.